# Live Streaming in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, streaming, xcode6, avplayer

I need to create a live streaming application in SWIFT

Tried many ways using AVFoundation framework (AVPLayer & AVPlayeritem) but didn't work

It's audio only so I don't want to do it in the webview way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You might try leveraging the [VideoCore](https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore) library that wraps these frameworks into a complete streaming package.  With this package, you can readily start publishing with little effort.  Take the following for consideration (replicated from their example projects):

To initiate a connection (Obj-C):

```
VCSimpleSession *sess = [[VCSimpleSession alloc] initWithVideoSize:CGSizeMake(width, height) frameRate:frameRate bitrate:bitrate] useInterfaceOrientation:YES];
sess.delegate = self;
```

To initiate a connection (Swift):

```
var sess:VCSimpleSession = VCSimpleSession(videoSize: CGSize(width: width, height: height), frameRate: frameRate, bitrate: bitRate, useInterfaceOrientation: false)
sess.delegate = self;
```

Utilize the event handler (Obj-C):

```
- (void) connectionStatusChanged:(VCSessionState) state{
   if(state==VCSessionStateStarting){
      // connecting to destination host
   }
   else if(state==VCSessionStateStarted){
     // connected, streaming has begun
   }
   // ... etc
}
```

Utilize the event handler (Swift):

```
func connectionStatusChanged(sessionState: VCSessionState) {
        switch session.rtmpSessionState {
        case .Starting:
            // initiating connection

        case .Started:
            // connected

        default:
           // connect
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, there are paid SDK's out there that you can get support on like [Wowza's GoCoder SDK](https://www.wowza.com/products/gocoder/sdk).  A slew more options and a stable infrastructure.

Thanks

Matt