# Video Calling using Wowza

Tags: ios, uiwebview, http-live-streaming, wowza

I want to integrate video calling in my application. I was using Wowza GoCoder SDK but in that I was facing problem to stream video on UIWebView. So, I integrated [JWPlayer](https://github.com/karimJWP/jwplayer-ios-videoFeed) but in that too I video was only buffering not streaming.

I searched about it alot and refer:
[Live Streaming in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960563/live-streaming-in-swift)

It was suggested to use [VideoCore](https://github.com/jgh-/VideoCore) library. With the VideoCore library reference, I was trying same procedure as mention in its readme.

After pod install its giving error:

> Re-creating CocoaPods due to major version update.
>
> Analyzing dependencies
>
> Downloading dependencies
>
> Installing UriParser-cpp (0.1.3)
>
> Installing VideoCore (0.3.2)
>
> Installing boost (1.51.0)
>
> [!] Error installing boost

Can anyone tell me solution of this problem? Or anyone can suggest me how I can implement video calling in my application using wowza? Or anyone having any sample for the same it would be very helpful.